# How to compile Detours Express 3.0?

Tags: c++, windows, detours

I have been recently trying to compile Microsoft's Detours library, The free version which is called "Express 3.0". In its README guide it's telling to use 'nmake'. I've opened a command window at the detours directory and tried 'nmake'.
It said: "nmake is not recognized as an internal command ...".

I've opened VS2015 x86 Native tools command prompt, used `cd` to change the current directory to that folder, then tried 'nmake all':

```
C:\Windows\system32>cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Research\Detours Express 3.0

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Research\Detours Express 3.0>nmake all

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.23026.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Research\Detours Express 3.0\src"
 Created ..\include
 Created ..\lib.X86
 Created ..\bin.X86
 Created obj.X86
        cl /W4 /WX /Zi /MTd /Gy /Gm- /Zl /Od /DDETOURS_BITS=32 /DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN /D_WIN32_WINNT=0x403 /Gs /DDETOURS_X86=1 /DDETOURS_32BIT=1 /D_X86_ /DDETOURS_OPTION_BITS=64 /Fd..\lib.X86\detours.pdb /Foobj.X86\detours.obj /c .\detours.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23026 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

detours.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\dbghelp.h(1544): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\dbghelp.h(1544): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of '' when no variable is declared
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\dbghelp.h(3190): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of '' when no variable is declared
.\detours.cpp(156): warning C4456: declaration of 'pbNew' hides previous local declaration
.\detours.cpp(156): note: to simplify migration, consider the temporary use of /Wv:18 flag with the version of the compiler with which you used to build without warnings
.\detours.cpp(147): note: see declaration of 'pbNew'
.\detours.cpp(163): warning C4456: declaration of 'pbNew' hides previous local declaration
.\detours.cpp(163): note: to simplify migration, consider the temporary use of /Wv:18 flag with the version of the compiler with which you used to build without warnings
.\detours.cpp(147): note: see declaration of 'pbNew'
.\detours.cpp(1263): warning C4456: declaration of 'o' hides previous local declaration
.\detours.cpp(1263): note: to simplify migration, consider the temporary use of /Wv:18 flag with the version of the compiler with which you used to build without warnings
.\detours.cpp(1112): note: see declaration of 'o'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Research\Detours Express 3.0>set DETOURS_TARGET_PROCESSOR=x86

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Research\Detours Express 3.0>nmake all

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.23026.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Research\Detours Express 3.0\src"
        cl /W4 /WX /Zi /MTd /Gy /Gm- /Zl /Od /DDETOURS_BITS=32 /DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN /D_WIN32_WINNT=0x403 /Gs /DDETOURS_X86=1 /DDETOURS_32BIT=1 /D_X86_ /DDETOURS_OPTION_BITS=64 /Fd..\lib.X86\detours.pdb /Foobj.X86\detours.obj /c .\detours.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23026 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

detours.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\dbghelp.h(1544): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\dbghelp.h(1544): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of '' when no variable is declared
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\dbghelp.h(3190): warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of '' when no variable is declared
.\detours.cpp(156): warning C4456: declaration of 'pbNew' hides previous local declaration
.\detours.cpp(156): note: to simplify migration, consider the temporary use of /Wv:18 flag with the version of the compiler with which you used to build without warnings
.\detours.cpp(147): note: see declaration of 'pbNew'
.\detours.cpp(163): warning C4456: declaration of 'pbNew' hides previous local declaration
.\detours.cpp(163): note: to simplify migration, consider the temporary use of /Wv:18 flag with the version of the compiler with which you used to build without warnings
.\detours.cpp(147): note: see declaration of 'pbNew'
.\detours.cpp(1263): warning C4456: declaration of 'o' hides previous local declaration
.\detours.cpp(1263): note: to simplify migration, consider the temporary use of /Wv:18 flag with the version of the compiler with which you used to build without warnings
.\detours.cpp(1112): note: see declaration of 'o'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Research\Detours Express 3.0>
```

What should I do? I use Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open "\src\Makefile" in your "Detours Express 3.0" Directory.

Modify line 19 as follows:

```
CFLAGS=/W3 /Zi /MTd /Gy /Gm- /Zl /Od /DDETOURS_BITS=$(DETOURS_BITS)
```

which means to change option "/W4" to "/W3" and remove option "/WX".

then redo "nmake".

Your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is telling you it is going to treat warnings as errors.  That means  if you have any warnings the compilation will fail.  You have warnings.

Try removing the `/WX` flag to the compiler in the make file or add the `/Wv:18` flag the compiler is suggesting to you.

Comment: I Think I Shouldn't compile it this way, Wouldn't be better to create a project is VS (Static library) and put the files in it? and then, Compile it?

Comment: That's up to you.  If they gave you a make file you should be able to use it.  What is the error now?